# Instructions framework integration with xib or nib by using UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am new in swift.I have integrated my project with [instruction framework from this github link](https://github.com/ephread/Instructions).I am getting hints on my app.I am trying to integrate my xib file which is of type UICollectionViewCell.Here is my code for integration.

```
  func coachMarksController(_ coachMarksController: CoachMarksController, coachMarkViewsAt index: Int, madeFrom coachMark: CoachMark) -> (bodyView: (UIView & CoachMarkBodyView), arrowView: (UIView & CoachMarkArrowView)?) {
        let coachViews = coachMarksController.helper.makeDefaultCoachViews(
               withArrow: true,
               arrowOrientation: coachMark.arrowOrientation
           )

           coachViews.bodyView.hintLabel.text = "Addition of student"
           coachViews.bodyView.nextLabel.text = "Ok!"
           return (bodyView: coachViews.bodyView, arrowView: coachViews.arrowView)
    }
    
    func coachMarksController(_ coachMarksController: CoachMarksController, coachMarkAt index: Int) -> CoachMark {
        var poi = UIView()
            poi = rightButton

       
        return coachMarksController.helper.makeCoachMark(for:poi )
        
    }
```

I am placing these functions from the documentation in to UICollectionViewCell.swift file and getting errors in comment.

```
  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) { 
//Method does not override any method from its superclass
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
//Value of type 'UICollectionViewCell' has no member 'viewDidAppear'
    
        self.coachMarksController.start(in: .window(over: self))
//Cannot convert value of type 'AppliancesListCVCell' to expected argument type //'UIViewController'
    }
    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
//Method does not override any method from its superclass
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
//Value of type 'UICollectionViewCell' has no member 'viewWillDisappear'
    
        self.coachMarksController.stop(immediately: true)
    }
```

The comments show the error.How i can work with framework by using UICollectionViewCell.

What is replacement of these two function that can integrate with this framework .Please help

Is it possible to use instruction framework with UICollectionViewCell?

Answer (score 0):

The methods `viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)` and `viewWillDisappear(animated:) are`UIViewController` methods.

The `UICollectionViewCell` class is a subclass of `UIView`, not `UIViewController`. It doesn't make sense to add those methods to a `UIView`.

Comment: Is it possible to use instruction framework with UICollectionViewCell?

Comment: I've never seen that framework before, but I assume it should be possible to use it in your project. It sounds like you need to attach it to the view controller that manages your view. So put it on the view controller that contains the collection view, not your `UICollectionViewCell`.

Comment: You should do some reading on the MVC design pattern to understand the difference between a view and a controller. A `UICollectionViewCell` is a view, and a UIViewController is a controller. Those are different animals that do different jobs.